# ERROR: Cannot create tracker (Message:session is not initialized) Sitecore 8.1 update 2

Tags: xdb, mongodb

I am getting below error in logs and none of the interaction data is collected in mongoDB also.
Verified with [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083886/xdb-not-storing-any-interactions/34085142) looks everything Ok in my solution.

```
ERROR Cannot create tracker.
    Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
    Message: session is not initialized
    Source: Sitecore.Analytics
       at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.HttpSessionContextManager.GetSession()
       at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureContext.Process(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
       at (Object , Object[] )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureSessionContextPipeline.Run(InitializeTrackerArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Analytics.DefaultTracker.EnsureSessionContext()
       at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateTracker.GetTracker.Process(CreateTrackerArgs args)
       at (Object , Object[] )
       at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
       at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Initialize()


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34083886/xdb-not-storing-any-interactions/34085142
```

Another error in log related to analytics I can see is below

```
3608 07:08:13 ERROR Media request analytics failed
Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
Message: Tracker.Current is not initialized
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartTracking.Process(PipelineArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.StartAnalytics.StartAnalyticsPipeline.Run()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.StartTracking()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestEventHandler.OnMediaRequest(Object sender, EventArgs args)
```

Comment: Check if you have below processor added to Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config in createVisit pipeline, if not added it. <processor type="Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.CreateVisits.InitializeWithRequestData, Sitecore.Analytics" />

Comment: What is your version of Sitecore?

Comment: navincumar- it is there .

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Sitecore 8.1 update 2

Comment: Do you have any other log errors that we should know about?

Comment: Did you change any session-related configuration? Have you by chance disabled sessions altogether?

Comment: did you disabled Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.RobotDetection.config  ?

Comment: @SitecoreClimber Robot detection should be of in CM only , I am getting error in CD as well as CM also

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko I am using Inproc default configuration in CM and in CD using shared session mode stored in mongoDB. Added one  related error for analytics I can observer but very few times.

Comment: Looks like this is specific to media item tracking. Have you tried adding     key to httpModules:                                                     <add type="Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection" name="MediaRequestSessionModule" /> ?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue with sitecore v 8.1.3 using XDB cloud. This was working for a time. As Faiyazul did I was able to verify that the cloud set was working using sitecore's API

Comment: This is a common question that is posted here. There are a lot of answers, but it is of my experience, that **EVERY** single time it comes up, its because the **Analytics.ClusterName** is incorrect.  All Sitecore Servers must be able to resolve the Analytics.ClusterName, which ***has*** to resolve to a reachable IP address of  a Content Delivery server.

Answer (score 8):

I have experienced both of the errors that you mention in an 8.1.2 instance - sometimes together and other times separately. The below are the most common causes and solutions for these issues, in my experience.

Note that it is possible for you to have more than one of these issues at a time.

**Tracking and xDB Disabled...**

The `Tracker.Current is not initialized` error most commonly occurs when you have xDB or Tracking disabled. Open your ShowConfig and verify that the `Xdb.Enabled` setting and the `Xdb.Tracking.Enabled` are set to `true`, and ensure the `enableTracking="true"` on your `<site>` configuration node.

Note that I am including this information as it may help others, but is most likely not the cause of your issue, since you also have `session is not initialized` error. However, if you do not get the `session is not initialized` error on your CM, this could be the cause of the issue on that instance and a different issue may exist on your CDs.

**Initialize Pipeline Errors or Aborts...**

Make sure that you don't have any errors or aborts in your initialize pipeline processors. If you do, this could be preventing the pipeline from reaching the `Sitecore.Analytics...` processors that initialize your `Tracker`.

**Session State Configuration is incorrect...**

This issue is sometimes caused by a error in Session State configuration, causing `Session` to be null and/or keeping it from being initialized. If this issue is happening on your CDs only, make sure that your CDs are correctly configured to use Shared Session State, and that there are no issues with your configuration (the most common issue I see is pointing your session provider at the wrong connection string name).

**If you are using xDB Cloud...**

If you are using xDB Cloud, reach out to Sitecore support and make sure that everything is associated properly with the license that you are using.

I have seen this error occur when an instance is configured to use xDB Cloud but the license on the server is not the one authorized for the xDB Cloud account. In other words, if your client purchased xDB Cloud but you have your Partner License up on the site or if there is a problem with your client's license then this error can occur.

You can sometimes identify this error by looking in your logs and checking for the "Valid xDB license present" message on initialize. However, if your license has an xDB Cloud license associated with it (which all up-to-date partner licenses should) then you will see this message, whether or not your license is associated with the same xDB Cloud account as you are connecting to.

**If you are not using xDB Cloud...**

If you are not using xDB Cloud but you are using a separate Reporting instance, be sure that you are able to connect to it as expected.

Comment: Zachary Kniebel Issue is on CD as well as CM both, I am trying to focus on CM - In CM default Inproc session is being used, and expected configuration are there. I have 1 CM, 4 CD, 1 Processing , Mongo replicaset(1 Primary, 1 Secondary, 1 arbitor) architecture. Checked connection of mongo servers from each sitecore server, looks fine. investigating on pipeline processor you mentioned.

Comment: @Zachary Kniebel I'm seeing the same error reported by FHN but have Xdb.Tracking.Enabled=true and Xdb.Enabled=false deliberately (we're not using MongoDBs etc and just need some simple personalisation rules to run). Do you have any ideas how I could address the error in that case?

Answer (score 2):

### Cannot Create Tracker or Tracker.Current is Not Initialized - Common Fixes

In almost every scenario that I have faced myself, as well as helping others, I have come to the utmost conclusion, that every single time this issue comes up is because of the following reasons:

#### Reason 1: Analytics.ClusterName is configured incorrectly.

The **Analytics.ClusterName** which is set in the *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config* needs to be a legitimate, resolvable hostname. The default "default-cd-cluster" is not enough to promote a working solution.  This value has to be a dns name that all Sitecore Servers can reach (e.g. **cd.cluster.domain.com** for example).

- Ensure that each server, at a minimum has the configured **Analytics.ClusterName** in the windows host file and configured to point to an IP address of a Content Delivery server.

  - If on a content delivery server, set this host file IP equal to localhost, which is 127.0.0.1.
  - If on a content management or other server, set the host file IP value equal to the IP of ONE of your CD servers. Do not set it to the load balancer IP (unless that can be reached by your network)

#### Reason 2: Analytics.Hostname is Incorrect

It has been my experience that setting a value for **Analytics.Hostname**, located in the *Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config* file does more harm than good. I have found leaving this value BLANK, makes everything work as it should.

#### Reason 3: Sitecore.Context.Page is not available.

Sitecore's Analytic **Tracker** requires that the `Sitecore.Context.Page` object be available in order for Tracker to be initialized. In certain cases where this object is not available, and Tracker tries to be started, it will throw this error.

Tracker cannot be utilized on ASHX's, internal pipelines or thread processes where Page is not set.

### Utilization of Tracker on Content Management Servers.

Pure (role configured) Content Management servers do not utilize session state management, and therefore can not run Tracker natively. Instead, they rely on the **Analytics.ClusterName** to resolve in order to communicate a session back to the Content Delivery servers. In cases where on the Content Management server, you receive these types of errors, it is because **Analytics.ClusterName** is not correctly setup and reachable.

This also applies to **Processing Servers**, **EXM Dispatch Servers**, and **Secondary Content Management Servers**.

### Want a Deep Dive Look?

Here is a [link to a blog post](https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/02/12/sitecore-analytics-tracker-common-issues-and-how-to-resolve-them) that I just published today as a result of this answer. In addition, I go into a deep dive behind the covers to reveal what's really going on when the Tracker is initialized and WHY the **Analytics.ClusterName** is so important.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you have disabled `Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.config` file (as suggested by Sitecore for CM Server) but you have not disabled the related module on Web.config files. 
In `system.webServer/modules` type of `MediaRequestSessionModule` module should be changed from `Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics.RobotDetection` to `Sitecore.Analytics.Media.MediaRequestSessionModule, Sitecore.Analytics`.

However, this has no effect in your analytic data collection. Zach mentioned a few good points and Sitecore has a good KB article on this as well that you can refer to https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/977445

My suggestion is double confirm your CD server configration according to Sitecore Disable Enable Excel sheet.