# Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact is null at controller post back action

Tags: xdb, experience-analytics

I have a form at my page and postback action to controller rendering, sitecore 8.2 I wounder why Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact is null at postback ?
at all other parts it works correctly including WebApi,

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CPostback(CPostbackModel postbackData)
{
    Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current.Contact - null 
}
```

how to fix it ?

```
@using(Html.BeginRouteForm(Sitecore.Mvc.Configuration.MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post, new { @class="comp-entry-form comp-entry-full-width" }))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("Comp","CPostback")
}
```

Comment: Do you have @Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification() in your main layout?

Comment: There is a good guide I am trying to find you for what could be wrong. But here is a start. https://sitecorehacker.com/2017/02/12/sitecore-analytics-tracker-common-issues-and-how-to-resolve-them/

Comment: Here you go. See Pete's answer. And the link above. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3666/error-cannot-create-tracker-messagesession-is-not-initialized-sitecore-8-1-u/3671#3671

Comment: @ChrisAuer yes I have... tracking not working at postback action only

Comment: @ChrisAuer tracking is not working only at this postback action (on local environment) , all other cases works fine. it is only regarding post back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I did it but in manyal way,

```
    var contactCookie = new Sitecore.Analytics.Web.ContactKeyCookie();
  contact = GetXdbContact(contactCookie.ContactId);
 public static Contact GetXdbContact(Guid identifier)
        {
            if (Tracker.Current != null && Tracker.Current.Contact != null)
            {
                //This is the current user
                return Tracker.Current.Contact;
            }

            //There is no Tracker.Current.Contact, so this must be running in some non-user context
            var repository = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/contactRepository", true) as ContactRepositoryBase;
            var sessionManager = Factory.CreateObject("tracking/sharedSessionState/manager", true) as SharedSessionStateManager;
            if (repository != null)
            {
                var dbContact = repository.LoadContactReadOnly(identifier);
                if (dbContact != null)
                {
                    //Now we have the Contact Id.  Use that Id to actually get the contact from shared session
                    var contactId = dbContact.ContactId;
                    if (sessionManager != null)
                    {
                        var sessionContact = sessionManager.LoadContactReadonly(contactId);
                        if (sessionContact != null)
                        {
                            return sessionContact;
                        }
                    }
                    return dbContact;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```